# Anchor Tag displayed as Text when dynamically replaced by Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following jquery code inmy javascript.

```
$('body:first :not(:has(*))').text(function (i, v)
{
   return v.replace(/(0\s?)([1-8]\s?)(\d\s?){8,9}/g, "<a class='phone_number_clicked' href=\"javascript:;\">$&</a>");
});
```

I loop through the body and then find the text match for a particular regex and replace it with a hyperlink.

However, when I run the page instead of hyperlink appearing the anchor tag is displayed.

Can somebody please help

Comment: where is HTML code ?where is css ,Use jsfiddle

Comment: Try HTML encoding the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change ".text()" in the above code to ".html()" and that did the trick. I was earlier replacing the expression as text instead of HTML.

```
$('body:first :not(:has(*))').html(function (i, v)
{
   return v.replace(/(0\s?)([1-8]\s?)(\d\s?){8,9}/g, "<a class='phone_number_clicked'    href=\"javascript:;\">$&</a>");
});
```